# ¿por que no dice resultado ODBC? si es mayor a 0

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, odbc, mssql

Estoy tratando de ejecutar este código desde php pero no arroja el resultado
**odbc_num_rows**

```
  $query1 = odbc_prepare($conn, "SELECT User FROM sqlsv2008r2.dbo.tabla WHERE email = ? ");
    $result_1 = odbc_execute($query1, array($email));
    if(odbc_num_rows($result_1)>0){die("<center><h2><font color='red'>El correo</font> <font color=#EEEA0B'>$email</font><font color='red'> NO esta Disponible</font></h2></center>");}else{die('Exito es lo que quiero');}
```

Me sale este error ¿Cómo lo soluciono?

```
Warning: odbc_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Web_2\ee\ar_.php on line 179
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El `odbc_execute` te devuelve `true` or `false` en función de si se ejecutó correctamente la sentencia sql o no.

Por otro lado, `odbc_num_rows` tiene como primer parametro el resultset. En tu caso, le estas poniendo el resultado del `odbc_execute`  que es un boolean en lugar de ponerle el resultset, que en este caso es `$query1`, por lo tanto, debería ser de este modo:

```
$query1 = odbc_prepare($conn, "SELECT User FROM sqlsv2008r2.dbo.tabla WHERE email = ? ");
    $result_1 = odbc_execute($query1, array($email));
    if($result_1 && odbc_num_rows($query1)>0){die("<center><h2><font color='red'>El correo</font> <font color=#EEEA0B'>$email</font><font color='red'> NO esta Disponible</font></h2></center>");}else{die('Exito es lo que quiero');
```